# Обработка символов '\| в URL по средствам JS

Tags: javascript

Есть клиенская сторона на JS. Для оправки данных на сервер использую AJAX. И перед этим формирую URL в котором могут присутствовать данные символы **'\|**.
Как их обработать? 
`encodeURIComponent()` не помогает. Получается URL  ***/mySite/api/-9/2016-12-19T18:00:00.000Z/'%5C%7C*** и дальше AJAX валится в failure. Если символы оправлять отдельно друг от друга, то все работает.

Comment: "Ajax валится в failure" - очень общее описание. Посмотрите, что конкретно происходит в Developer Tools Chrome, вкладки Network и Console. Может, проблема на стороне сервера?

Comment: Нет до сервера запрос даже не доходит. Валится с сообщением не корректный URL

Comment: У вас там одинарная кавычка перед `%5C%7C`. Что она тут забыла в url?

Comment: Потому что она может быть там. Последние символы это комментарий или что-то еще. Но почему-то она не кодируется.

Comment: Тут https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent есть пример функции `fixedEncodeURIComponent()`. Попробуйте ее вместо `encodeURIComponent()` использовать.

Comment: Покажите сообщение про некорректный url. Желательно скриншот.

Comment: Сервер переписывай)

Comment: Похоже единственный выход вот здесь [ссылка]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298770/how-do-you-pass-a-single-quote-through-a-url

Comment: @cronfy 404(Not Found) ошибка лезет

Comment: Соответственно, ошибка на стороне сервера. Это он не понимает ваш запрос. А отправляется все нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Обратный слэш **"\"** используется для экранирования служебных символов, скорее всего из-за этого всё и валится. Если хотите в строке отправить один символ **"\"**, то вы должны его экранировать, т.е. отправлять два обратных слэша, вместо одного **"\\"**